# The location of pulmonary valve in comparison with the aortic valve

Tags: human-anatomy, cardiology

[image]

According to most transverse diagrams of heart, the pulmonary valve, in comparison to the aortic valve, angles  towards the left side a little bit. Take, for instance, the pulmonary valve is more close to the left coronary artery than the right one. But the frontal sections, on the contrary, show that the pulmonary valve, in comparison to the aortic valve, angles toward right.

What's wrong?

Comment: They both look angled to the left to me. On the left image, left is to the left (you're looking from the top down, as if you came up behind someone and looked through their skull into the torso). On the right image, left is to the right; you're looking straight ahead at someone's chest from the front.

Comment: @BryanKrause Forget the angles, for the moment, let's talk about their location. I've edited the image.

Comment: I think you're reading too much into the picture. They're basically right on top of each other, and they are crossing along the length. In one you're emphasizing the bottom leaflets of the valves, in the other the top. I don't think there's a meaningful anatomical distinction between the two. That said, I'm a bit more familiar with porcine cardiac anatomy which is more different than these pictures. Maybe someone will have an answer I just don't see why this is important to you.

Comment: @BryanKrause One of those vague 'why' questions! I just wonder whether it is actually possible to see the aortic valve in a longitudinal section of the heart or the frontal diagrams are just trying to emphasis on showing that, on its presence.

Comment: Well it's certainly visible in *some* longitudinal section. The [help](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) suggests "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." - it's hard to get good answers if you can't explain the *purpose* of a question.

Comment: @BryanKrause Quite agree. Though it is rather personal, let me ask, if you were to choose a frontal diagram for an atricle, what diagram would you choose, the right image, or a version in which the aortic valve is completely hidden?

Comment: The image to choose would entirely depend on the goals I had in displaying the image. I'd never put a figure in an article/paper without a purpose.

Comment: @BryanKrause It is going to be a typical illustration of the heart chambers with 15-18 year old audience